# Unity Transform GetChild() works weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I have 4 objects but when i deleting GameObject in transform.GetChild(n) deleted object still alive.

[Before deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXJqm.png)

[After deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PvhL.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgMu6.png)

```
IEnumerator DeletePlanet(int item) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    planets.RemoveAt(item);
    Destroy(transform.GetChild(item).gameObject);
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.Count; i++) {
        UpdatePositions(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), i);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < startPlanetCount; i++) {
        print(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition);
    }
}
```

Idk what can i do here.

Comment: As I do not see any problem, is this just out of curiosity or is there an actual problem? If the first, please state so in the question. In his answer, CrippledTable speaks about the garbage collector.

Comment: @Willem The deleted destruction of an object is not garbage collection. Unity's documentation suggests that a GameObject's "destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but is always done before rendering". Whereas the default garbage collection behaviour "spreads out the process of garbage collection over multiple frames". A destroyed game object is fully destroyed before the next frame. The memory fragments of that object aren't necessarily destroyed/released-by-the-garbage-collector before the next frame.

Comment: It seems to me the passed object will be collected by the method `Destroy`. Think I will dive into the garbage collector to get a better understanding of it. But that's appearntly out of the scope of this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two things going on here.

1. The script is removing the item from the parents transform before deleting it, so the object is no longer accessible using `transform.GetChild`
2. The script assumes that a destroyed object is instantly destroyed, but it is not. In an update method, the object is destroyed [after the update method is finished](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html#:%7E:text=Description,if%20a%20time%20is%20specified.). I'm not sure when an object is destroyed during a coroutine, but my guess is after the coroutines finishes or after a yield.

Comment: yeah, issue was in coroutine. I just added WaitForEndOfFrame() and its worked